# Measure Theory: Proof regarding a measurability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Is my proof for the following problem correct?

Let $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ and $X=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ be measurable.
Prove: $f$ is measurable $\iff$ $f\cdot\chi_{A_i}$ is measurable.

Proof:
"$\implies$" Let f be $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}s_n(x)=f(x)$ $\forall x\in X$(where $s_n$ is a sequence of simple functions).
Then the following holds:
$\int_Xf(x)\:d\mu=\int_{\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i}f(x)\:d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{A_i}f(x)\:d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_Xf(x)\cdot\chi_{A_i}d\mu$.

"$\impliedby$" Let $f\cdot\chi_{A_i}$ be measurable.
Then the following holds:
$\int_Xf(x)\cdot\chi_{A_i}\:d\mu=\int_{\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i}f(x)\cdot\chi_{A_i}\:d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{A_i}f(x)\cdot\chi_{A_i}\:d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{X}f(x)\cdot\chi_{A_i}\cdot\chi_{A_i}\:d\mu=$
$\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{X}f(x)\cdot\chi_{A_i}\:d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{A_i}f(x)\:d\mu=\int_{\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i}f(x)\:d\mu=\int_X f(x)\:d\mu.$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: You talk about measurability and then you proceed to compute integrals. You need measurability to *be able to* (potentially) compute integrals. Your attempted proof says pretty much nothing about measurability. (Rather, it looks like you're trying to argue about integrability perhaps?) And for the claim to be true you need at least each $A_i$ to be measurable.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true that $ \int _ { \bigcup _ i A _ i } f = \sum _ i \int _ { A _ i } f $ unless the $ A _ i $ are all disjoint (or at least have intersections of measure zero).  And even then, I'm not sure how you would prove that integrals decompose like this without already knowing at least the $ \Longrightarrow $ direction of this theorem, unless maybe you make measurability on each set a hypothesis (in which case this doesn't help you).

More than that, thinking about integrals is bound to be a bad approach to this.  Measurability is about the algebra of measurable sets, not the measure.  (In fact, if you use a measure to prove the theorem, then you're relying on the theorem that every measurable space has a measure on it; which is true, but have you proved that yet?)

You began with a totally different approach, writing $ f $ as the limit of a sequence of simple measurable functions.  This seems more promising to me.  For each $ i $, you can convert this sequence into a sequence of simple measurable functions that converges to $ f \chi _ { A _ i } $ (assuming that each $ A _ i $ is measurable, thanks to @tomasz for catching that); this will prove the $ \Longrightarrow $ direction.  To prove the $ \Longleftarrow $ direction is more involved, but if you have a sequence of sequences of simple measurable functions, so that $ f \chi _ { A _ i } = \lim _ j s _ { i , j } $, then with some work you can convert this into a single sequence of measurable functions whose limit is $ f $.